# why my angular 2 service in not visible to my app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular

I am trying to read JSON file through my angular service.
When I am not using the service I can easily read JSON data & bind it inside variable.
But When I am using service to perform this,its not working.
Its showing following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404.
```

I am sure that I have written path correctly.

**Directory Structure**
[image]

Below are is the code:

1. app.component.ts

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [DataService],
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    public record;
    constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataService.getDetails()
        .subscribe((customers:any[]) => {
          this.record = customers;
        });              
    }  
}
```

2. data.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Http, Response } from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {    
    constructor(private http: Http) { }    
    getDetails() {
        return this.http.get('../uicomponent.json')
            .map((res:Response) => res.json());     
    }
}
```

3. bootstrap config

```js
<script>
      System.config({
        map: { 'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs' },
        packages: {
          app: { format: 'register', defaultExtension: 'js' },
          'rxjs': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
        }
      });
      System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

4. main.ts

```js
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
 
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS
]);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you think Angular is not finding the service (like the question title suggests) or that the service is not able to fetch the json file? What URL is requested and how should it actually be?

Comment: angular 2 is not able to find the service..though I have written path correctly..because I had used service in same manner in other projects, they are working properly @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Your path seems to be valid. Can you share more information like SystemJS or Webpack config, maybe your repository or plunker... ?

Comment: Could you provide the complete error message? I mean which resource loading fails... Thanks!

Comment: I guess the problem could come from your relative path (`'../uicomponent.json'`)...

Comment: @ThierryTemplier I tried giving absolute path too.. json is getting read using same path.. error message is this: Failed to load resource: localhost:3000/app/service/data.service the server responded with a status of 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `services` folder should be under the `app` folder. According to your SystemJS configuration, only resources under this folder are loaded using this configuration:

```
System.config({
  (...),
  packages: {
    app: { format: 'register', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    (...)
  }
});
format: 'register', defaultExtension: 'js'
```

This means that SystemJS will automatically try to load modules using the `js` extension.

So the structure should be the following:

```
project
  - app
    - app.component.ts
    - main.ts
    - services
      - data.service.ts
```

Within the `app.component.ts` file, you can import the service using:

```
import {DataService} from './services/data.service';
```

According to its configuration, SystemJS will try to load the `localhost:3000/app/services/data.service.js` that should be present if the TypeScript compiler did its job before ;-)

Thierry